# Mutual authentication always succeeds with OpenSSL

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, mutual-authentication

I am using openssl and zmq to write a server and a client.
My client and server need mutual authentication. 
but after I set `SSL_CTX_set_verify(ssl_ctx,SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT,NULL)` on server, the handshake always successes whether the client send the certificate or not. 
In addition, `SSL_get_peer_certificate(tls->get_ssl_())` return null and `SSL_get_verify_result(tls->get_ssl_())` return 0 which means `X509_V_OK`.

I am really confused and desperate now. Any suggestions or corrections?

This is part of my code:

```
OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
SSL_library_init();
SSL_load_error_strings();
ERR_load_BIO_strings();

const SSL_METHOD *meth;
SSL_CTX *ssl_ctx;

     //**************************part of client************************
  {
    meth = SSLv23_client_method();
    ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);   


    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ssl_ctx,SSL_VERIFY_PEER,NULL);

    int rc1 = SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ssl_ctx, ".\\demoCA\\private\\server_chain.pem",".\\demoCA\\private\\");///   
     SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(ssl_ctx,"pw");

     std::string cert_chain(".\\demoCA\\private\\client_chain.pem");
     std::string cert(".\\demoCA\\private\\client_crt.pem");
     std::string key(".\\demoCA\\private\\client_key.pem");

     int code = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ssl_ctx,cert_chain.c_str());

     if (code != 1)
    {
         std::cout<<"error1\n";
        //throw TLSException("failed to read credentials.");
     }
    code = SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ssl_ctx,key.c_str(),SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);   
    i f (code != 1)
    {
        std::cout<<"error2\n";
        //throw TLSException("failed to read credentials.");
    }
    if(!SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ssl_ctx))
    {
        std::cout<<"key wrong";
        system("pause");
        exit(0);
    }
   }

//*****************part of server****************************
{
    meth = SSLv23_server_method();
    ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(meth);

    SSL_CTX_set_verify(ssl_ctx,SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT,NULL)   
    SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(ssl_ctx,SSL_load_client_CA_file(".\\demoCA\\private\\client_chain.pem"));//

    SSL_CTX_set_default_passwd_cb_userdata(ssl_ctx,"pw");

    std::string cert_chain(".\\demoCA\\private\\server_chain.pem");
    std::string cert(".\\demoCA\\private\\server_crt.pem");
    std::string key(".\\demoCA\\private\\server_key.pem");

    int rc = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file(ssl_ctx,cert.c_str(),SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

    if (rc!=1)
    {
        //throw TLSException("failed to read credentials.");
        std::cout<<"error1\n";
    }

    rc = SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ssl_ctx,key.c_str(),SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);

    if (rc!=1)
    {
        //throw TLSException("failed to read credentials.");   
        std::cout<<"error2\n";
    }

    int rcode = SSL_CTX_check_private_key(ssl_ctx);
    if(rcode!=1)
    {
        std::cout<<"key wrong";
        system("pause");
        //exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Also see [Library Initialization](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Library_Initialization) on the OpenSSL wiki. There's no need for the four startup calls you make.

Comment: you mean this ? OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
SSL_library_init();
SSL_load_error_strings();
ERR_load_BIO_strings();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation of SSL_CTX_set_verify](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_verify.html):

> SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT
>
> Server mode: if the client did not return a certificate, the TLS/SSL handshake is immediately terminated with a "handshake failure" alert. **This flag must be used together with SSL_VERIFY_PEER.**

You did not use it together with `SSL_VERIFY_PEER` as described in the documentation and thus it has no effect.

Comment: God! Thanks a lot !!! I 'v noticed that note ,but i took it wrong way , i thought that means use SSL_VERIFY_PEER on client !

Comment: Thanks so much, for stopping me wasting more time on this stupid mistake.

Comment: hey... ..I have got another problem here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29211061/using-openssl-with-its-unblocked-bio-ssl-read-return-ssl-error-syscall-and-ssl  . Woud you please take a look at it? What may call this kind of problem, any ideas?