# using openssl with its unblocked bio, ssl_read return SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL and SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ

Tags: c++, ssl, openssl, zeromq

I use zeromq and openssl to write my server and client .

After successful handshake, when the client sends message to server again, the ssl_read() in server returns -1 and ssl_get_erro() returns SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL,

this situation repeats when server receives messages again. I cannot find the reason. Do i need BIO_flush()? I would really appreciate you even just give me some inspirations to work this out.

---

well, my program is too complicated to show. I was asked to add ssl to rpcz to improve its security (I dont know if rpcz is popular enough for most people to know. In my word ,it combines zeromq,protobuf and rpc to realize remote procedure call).
So there are lots of pieces of code, I think it wont help by showing them all here.

I am trying to give more details.

After a successful handshake, when server try to decrypt the data it receives, using a method like this

```
`{
  //.......
  bio_write();
  //.......
  ssl_read();
}`
```

and it turns out that bio_write() has successfully written the data into bio by returning number of the data, but ssl_read() always retun -1. So I use ssl_get_error() to check the error number, it returns SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, and for the next data received,it returns SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ.

hope that someone can help to explain why ssl_read returns these code? I think if the ssl connection does not handshake successfully, ssl_write() wont return a positive number. So may the problem is not the ssl connection.

---

add some details again

```
void TLSZmq::ssl_decrypt()
{
    //........
    ERR_clear_error();
    int rc = BIO_write(rbio,zmq_to_ssl->data(),zmq_to_ssl->size()); 
    ERR_get_error();
    check_ssl_err(rc); //written by myself
    //.........
    ERR_clear_error();      
    aread = SSL_read(ssl_,buffer,BUFFERSIZE);
    ERR_get_error();
    check_ssl_err(rc); //written by myself
    //..........
}

  void TLSZmq::check_ssl_err(int rc)
{
    //...................
    int err = SSL_get_error(ssl_, rc);
    if (err == SSL_ERROR_NONE)
    {
        std::cout<<"SSL_ERROR_NONE:"<<SSL_ERROR_NONE<<std::endl;
    }
    else if (err == SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ ) 
    { 
        std::cout<<"SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ:"<<SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ<<std::endl;
    }
    else if (SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL)
    {
        std::cout<<"SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL:"<<SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL<<std::endl;          

    }

    //.....................
}
```

I am not sure this is the right way to check the error stack or something. when SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL appears, ERR_get_error() return a strange number like 336130315, and when SSL_ERROR_WANT_READ appears, ERR_get_error() returns 0.

### I also have tested that the ssl connection(SSL* ssl) which is used by decrypt procedure after handshake is as same as it used during the handshake .

er...we are talking openssl right? rc gets the return value of BIO_write() function of openssl. P.S. I use zeromq socket for sending message, which I have pointed out. I am confused. Does it make sense to get errno by or call perror() ?

---

Really thanks for your time reading this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Please format your comments to enable readability and try to avoid repeating your requests for help (eg, any suggestions?).

Comment: Hard to have any insight into your situation without seeing any code.  The error could come from any number of causes.

Comment: If you get an error attributable to any system call you must either: print `errno`; call `perror();` or print the string resulting from `str_error().` Any you must do that before performing any other system calls that could change the `errno.` And you must post the result here, in your question. I would say offhand that you probably have an `ECONNRESET` on your hands, but it's impossible to be certain without further information from you. If you get -1 from any system call or SSL function the connection is almost certainly lost, and it is almost certainly futile to continue as though it isn't.

Comment: It is far from clear from your edit that you're getting `errno` before it has been altered. Where for example is `rc` set? And what is it set to? Don't write code like this., and certainly don't ever write obscure error-handling code. Keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: er...we are talking openssl right? rc gets the return value of BIO_write() function of openssl.   P.S. I use zeromq socket for sending message, which I have pointed out. I am confused. Does it make sense to get errno  by or call perror() ?

Comment: The return value of BIO_write() is -1 or a write count. Not very interesting, and not worth passing to another function. What's important is the `errno,` and there continues to be zero evidence as to what it actually is, or that that you're capturing it correctly, due to your poorly structured code. You call `BIO_write(),` then `ERR_get_error(),` then `check_ssl_err()`, and *nowhere* are you doing anything like one of thre three things I said you have to do above.

Comment: Are you expecting SSL to work over your transport, even though you don't replicate the behavior of TCP? Or are you expecting this code to encrypt and decrypt without actually using the SSL protocol? I'm pretty sure that you have one of these misconceptions, but it's not clear which.

Answer (score 1):

An SSL connection is not a decryption function and an encryption function that can be used independently. If you want a block or stream cipher, you can get one using the OpenSSL code for some of the pieces. But you can't use SSL *itself* that way.

It is possible to use BIO pairs to allow SSL to operate over a transport layer other than TCP. But you have to replicate the semantics of TCP -- it's complex, and the code looks nothing like the code you have above. (For example, TCP permits transmission in either direction at any time. You don't replicate that. SSL, designed to be layered on top of TCP, requires you to replicate that for it to work on some other transport.)

If you want a stream cipher, just use one.

Comment: In fact maybe he *is* getting EWOULDBLOCK on his native reads. Until he tells us, it's anybody's guess though.

Comment: @EJP If so, he should ignore that. The SSL engine may get `EWOULDBLOCK` on native reads but may still be able to make forward progress without waiting for them to complete. It's a mistake to try to "look through" the SSL engine -- he should just do what the SSL engine tells him to do.

Comment: guys, I am NOT using winsock....so it is not sockets' fault TAT...I make use of openssl's unblocked bio only for encrypting and decrypting, and leave the communicating thing to zeromq. In this condition I dont even have to learn what TCP is.... TAT

Comment: @601492584 You can't use SSL that way. SSL requires things like protocol negotiation. If you want a block or stream cipher, you can use OpenSSL for them, but not with `SSL_read`. Are you trying to use SSL and proxy between the SSL engine and the zeromq connection? If so, you're doing it *all* wrong.

Comment: Yes I think I can...I just need to bind my ssl and bio together with ssl_set_bio(), and I can get handshake info from ssl_write,bio_read,bio_write and ssl_read when handshake is needed, and then all I have to do is sending those info to another zmq socket.

Comment: Yes, you can do that. But you have to replicate TCP's semantics. You can't say "I just gave the SSL engine some plaintext, so now it's going to want to send the encrypted data" because TCP *doesn't* do that. You really do have to replicate TCP's full-duplex "I can send and receive at any time" semantics, allowing the SSL engine to do that. And you have to use BIO pairs.