# Mutual Authentication and restricting user certificates to specific set at server

Tags: c, openssl, server

I'm looking for a way to restrict client certificates to specific set of self-signed certificates on the server side using the OpenSSL API.

There is a set of trusted self-signed certificates, say `./dir/*.pem`. I want to reject connections, if they don't supply one of those certificates.

I can achieve *almost* desired behaviour by comparing server and client certificate fingerprints in the SSL context verification callback:

```c
SSL_CTX *ctx;
...

SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, verify_callback);


static inline int get_fingerprint(X509* cert, unsigned char *md, unsigned int *n)
{
  return X509_digest(cert, EVP_sha1(), md, n);
}


static inline int compare_certificates(X509 *c1, X509 *c2)
{
  unsigned char md1[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE], md2[EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE];
  unsigned int n1, n2;

  if (!(get_fingerprint(c1, md1, &n1) && get_fingerprint(c2, md2, &n2))) {
    return -1;
  }

  return memcmp(md1, md2, n1);
}


static int verify_callback(int preverify_ok, X509_STORE_CTX *ctx)
{
  SSL *ssl = X509_STORE_CTX_get_ex_data(ctx, SSL_get_ex_data_X509_STORE_CTX_idx());
  int  err = X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(ctx);

  /* Allow self-signed certificates */
  if (!preverify_ok && err == X509_V_ERR_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT) {
    preverify_ok = 1;
  }

  if (0 != compare_certificates(ctx->current_cert, SSL_CTX_get0_certificate(ssl->ctx))) {
    /* Peer certificate doesn't match the server certificate */
    preverify_ok = 0;
  }

  /* More checks ... */

  return preverify_ok;
}
```

So if the server and client certificate fingerprints match, verification passes. Otherwise, connection is closed by the server.

I might compute fingerprints of the trusted certificates somewhere in initialization phase, then check them in a loop within the `verify_callback`. However, I don't like this idea. There should be easier way to do this.

I thought `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()` is just what I was looking for(*but it looks like it's not; i'll explain why*):

> SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations() specifies the locations for ctx, at which CA certificates for verification purposes are located.
>   ...
>   If CAfile is not NULL, it points to a file of CA certificates in PEM format. The file can contain several CA certificates...
>   The certificates in CApath are only looked up when required, e.g. when building the certificate chain or when actually performing the verification of a peer certificate.

([man 3 SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations.html))

Well, I guess `SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT` implies verifying the peer certificate. Then it looks like all I need to do is to make a bundle of trusted certificates and pass it to `SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations()`:

```shell
bundle_file=CAbundle.pem

cd ./dir
rm -f $bundle_file

for i in *.pem; do
  openssl x509 -in $i -text >> $bundle_file
done

c_rehash .
```

```c
SSL_CTX *ctx;
const char *cafile = "dir/CAbundle.pem";
const char *capath = NULL;
...

if (!SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations(ctx, cafile, capath)) {
      /* Unable to set verify locations ... */
}

cert_names = SSL_load_client_CA_file(cafile);
if (cert_names != NULL) {
  SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list(ctx, cert_names);
} else {
  /* Handle error ... */
}
```

All looks good. But the server still accepts connections with different peer certificates.

I've reproduced this behaviour using standard OpenSSL utilities here: https://gist.github.com/rosmanov/d960a5d58a96bdb730303c5b8e86f951

So my question is: how do I configure the server to accept only peers providing only specific certificates?

**Update**

I've found that the "whitelist" of certificates (CA bundle) actually works,
when I *remove* the following from the `verify_callback`:

```c
if (!preverify_ok && err == X509_V_ERR_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT) {
  preverify_ok = 1;
}
```

So without this block everything just works. The server responds to a client connected with one of certificates listed in `CAbundle.pem`. If a client connects with different certificate, the server closes connection.

However, there is a strange thing. In both cases `openssl s_client` outputs:

```
Verify return code: 18 (self signed certificate)
```

Then maybe

```c
if (!preverify_ok
    && err == X509_V_ERR_DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT
    && allow_self_signed
    && !cafile
    && !capath) {
  preverify_ok = 1;
}
```

?

**Update 2**

Now I understand why `openssl s_client` outputs `Verify return code: 18 (self signed...)`. It doesn't trust server's certificate unless `-CAfile` or `-CApath` contains the server certificate. And the server certificate is self-signed.

Comment: Also see Steffens' answer at [Openssl mutual authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28392363/608639).

Comment: Per your gist (a;lso here, assuming the same files as the gist) you put cert1 and cert2 into `CAbundle.pem`; then you tell `s_server` to accept `-CAfile CAbundle.pem` and you tell `s_client` to use (a copy of) cert2. cert2 is in the file so `s_server` accepts it. If you want the server to not accept cert2, don't include cert2 in the truststore (file and/or directory) you give the server. PS: `c_rehash` is irrelevant for a CA *file* like `CAbundle`; it is only used for a CA *directory* like `-CApath` on `s_server`/`s_client` or the third argument to `_load_verify_locations`.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, nope, I move `cert2*` from current directory before building `CAbundle.pem`: `mv cert2* /tmp`. I actually used `c_rehash` for `-CApath`; yes, it's not appropriate here.

Comment: You're right; I missed that. See possible answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An explanation (for commandline) and a halfanswer (for library):

I (this time fully) redid your gist and was reminded of an inconsistency here. Commandline `openssl xxx` utilities are mostly designed as test/debugging tools, and in particular:

- `s_client` normally (except anonymous, SRP, etc) receives a cert chain from the server, but uses a callback that only logs what it got and **ignores/overrides any error**; this is the block

  ```
  depth=0 C = AU, ST = StateA, L = CityA, O = CompanyA, CN = localhost, emailAddress = a@gmail.com
  verify error:num=18:self signed certificate
  verify return:1
  depth=0 C = AU, ST = StateA, L = CityA, O = CompanyA, CN = localhost, emailAddress = a@gmail.com
  verify return:1
  ```

  just after `CONNECTED(fd)` in your `s_client` output, but as you see in spite of the error it continues with the handshake resulting in a usable connection.
- `s_server` is a more complicated. It does not request a cert from client by default, only if you specify `-verify` or `-Verify` (which set `SSL_VERIFY_PEER` which is not the default for server), and if it does request a cert client has the *option* whether to send one (with associated proof in CertVerify). *If* client does send chain, `s_server` uses the same callback as `s_client` which overrides any error and continues with the connection; this in your `s_server` output with the same `verify error:num-18...` which actually means 'root (including selfsigned which is its own root) in received chain but not in local truststore'. *If* client does not send chain, `-verify` continues, but `-Verify` (which *also* sets `SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT`) aborts the handshake with alert 40 and returns an error, so the `s_server` output is very different:

```
    verify depth is 0, must return a certificate
    Using default temp DH parameters
    Using default temp ECDH parameters
    ACCEPT
    ERROR
    140679792887624:error:140890C7:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE:peer did not return a certificate:s3_srvr.c:3271:
    shutting down SSL
    CONNECTION CLOSED
    ACCEPT
```

---

But a **program using the library should work**. I hacked up this simple test from parts of some other programs (hence the odd indentation):

```
/* SO36821430 2016-04-25 */

#include <stdio.h>
#if defined(_WIN32)&&!defined(WIN32)
#define WIN32 /*anything*/
#endif
#ifdef WIN32
  #include <winsock2.h>
  typedef int socklen_t;
  #define SOCKERR WSAGetLastError()
  #include "openssl/applink.c"
#else
  #include <unistd.h>
  #include <sys/socket.h>
  #include <netinet/in.h>
  #include <arpa/inet.h>
  #ifndef INADDR_NONE
  #define INADDR_NONE (ipaddr_t)-1
  #endif
  typedef int SOCKET;
  enum { INVALID_SOCKET = -1, SOCKET_ERROR = -1 };
  #define SOCKERR errno
  #define closesocket close
#endif

#include "openssl/ssl.h"
#include "openssl/err.h"
#include "openssl/rand.h"

void sockerr (const char *what){
  fprintf (stderr, "%s %d %s\n", what, SOCKERR, strerror(SOCKERR));
}
void sslerrn (const char *what){
  fprintf (stderr, "* %s failed:\n", what);
  ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
}
void sslerr (const char *what, int rv){
  fprintf (stderr, "* %s return %d:\n", what, rv);
  ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr);
}
void sslerrx (SSL * ssl, const char *what, int rv){
  int rc = SSL_get_error (ssl, rv);
  if( rv == -1 && rc == SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL ) sockerr (what);
  else fprintf (stderr, "* %s return %d,%d\n", what, rv, rc);
  ERR_print_errors_fp (stderr); 
}
void subj_oneline (X509 * cert, FILE *fp){
  X509_NAME * subj = X509_get_subject_name (cert);
  BIO *bmem = BIO_new (BIO_s_mem()); char *ptr; int n;
  X509_NAME_print_ex (bmem, subj, 0, XN_FLAG_ONELINE); 
  n = (int) BIO_get_mem_data (bmem, &ptr);
  if( n <= 0 ) ptr = "?", n = 1;
  fwrite (ptr,1,n,fp);
}

const char * inaddr;
int inport;
char buf [9999];

int main (int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  int rv; 
  struct sockaddr_in sin; socklen_t sinlen;
  SOCKET s1, s2; SSL_CTX *ctx = NULL;
  time_t now; struct tm * tm;
#ifdef WIN32
  struct WSAData wsa;
  rv = WSAStartup (MAKEWORD(1,1), &wsa);
  if(rv){ printf ("WSAStartup %d\n", rv); exit(1); }
#endif

  if( argc < 2 || argc > 6 )
    printf ("usage: %s port key cert CAcerts\n", argv[0]), exit(1);
  sin.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  sin.sin_port = htons (atoi(argv[1]));
  sin.sin_family = AF_INET;

  /**/
    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();
    ctx = SSL_CTX_new (SSLv23_server_method());
    if( !ctx ){ sslerrn("CTX_new"); exit(1); }
    SSL_CTX_set_options (ctx, SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2|SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3);
    rv = SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file (ctx, argv[2], SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    if( rv != 1 ){ sslerr ("use_PrivateKey_file",rv); exit(1); }
    rv = SSL_CTX_use_certificate_file (ctx, argv[3], SSL_FILETYPE_PEM);
    if( rv != 1 ){ sslerr ("use_certificate_file",rv); exit(1); }
    SSL_CTX_set_verify (ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER | SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT, NULL); 
    if( !SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations (ctx, argv[4], NULL) ){
      sslerrn ("load_verify_locations"); exit(1); }
    SSL_CTX_set_client_CA_list (ctx, SSL_load_client_CA_file (argv[4]));
  /**/
  if( (s1 = socket (AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) == INVALID_SOCKET ){
    sockerr ("socket()"); exit(1); }
  if( bind (s1, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof sin) < 0 ){
    sockerr ("bind()"); exit(1); }
  if( listen (s1, 5) < 0 ){
    sockerr ("listen()"); exit(1); }

  do{
    sinlen = sizeof sin;
    if( (s2 = accept (s1, (struct sockaddr*)&sin, &sinlen)) == INVALID_SOCKET ){
      sockerr ("accept()"); exit(1); }
    now = time(NULL); tm = localtime(&now);
    printf ("+ %s %u @%02d.%02d.%02d\n", inet_ntoa (sin.sin_addr),
      ntohs (sin.sin_port), tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);

    /**/
      SSL * ssl = SSL_new (ctx);
      if( !ssl ){ sslerrn("SSL_new"); goto next; }
      SSL_set_fd (ssl, s2);
      if( (rv = SSL_accept(ssl)) < 0 ){
        sslerrx (ssl, "SSL_accept", rv); goto next; }
      { X509 * cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate (ssl);
        /*EVP_PKEY * key = cert? X509_get_pubkey (cert): NULL;*/
        fprintf (stdout, "=%ld", SSL_get_verify_result (ssl));
        if( cert ) putchar (':'), subj_oneline (cert, stdout);
        putchar ('\n');
      }
      while( (rv = SSL_read (ssl, buf, sizeof buf)) > 0 )
        printf ("%d: %.*s\n", rv, rv, buf);
      sslerrx (ssl, "SSL_read", rv);
next:
      if( ssl ) SSL_free (ssl);
    /**/
    now = time(NULL); tm = localtime(&now);
    printf ("- %s %u @%02d.%02d.%02d\n", inet_ntoa (sin.sin_addr),
      ntohs (sin.sin_port), tm->tm_hour, tm->tm_min, tm->tm_sec);
    closesocket (s2);
  } while (1);
  return 0;
}
```

When run with `$port cert1.key cert1.pem CAbundle.pem` and connected from client using cert2.key & cert2.pem this aborts the handshake with alert 48 unknown_ca and returns an error as desired:

```
+ 127.0.0.1 46765 @22.07.36
* SSL_accept return -1,1
140240689366696:error:14089086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_client_certificate:certificate verify failed:s3_srvr.c:3270:
- 127.0.0.1 46765 @22.07.36
```

HTH.

Comment: It turned out that it didn't work because of a block in `verify_callback` which allowed any self-signed certificate. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a whitelist of specific client certificates, you can prepare an indexed list in memory when you initialize.

For example, you can use `PEM_X509_INFO_read` to read a concatenated file of all client certificates in PEM format. This will give you a `STACK_OF(X509_INFO)*` of certificates. The number of certificates can be found with `sk_X509_INFO_num`, and you can see each certificate at `sk_X509_INFO_value(..)->x509`.

Then, for example, you can simply build an in-memory index and `qsort` by `compare_x509`.

Now, when your verify callback is called, just do a `bsearch` on your index by `compare_x509`, and either the certificate is on your whitelist, or it isn't.

You can accept the match on the result of `compare_x5099`, or of course you could double-check by verifying the full certificate once the search finds a match in the index.

Comment: I thought of that, but there was a feeling that OpenSSL can do it easier. I've recently found that the "whitelist" didn't work just because my `verify_callback` allowed _any_ self-signed certificate (the question is updated)